# What's the HTML protocol?

Tags: html, protocol, network-protocols

I read a document, there is examples in TCP/IP layer.

[image]

you see there is a HTML protocol, but I do not hear about it. is it mean HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is not a network protocol. It is the language in which webpages are written.

And there is more wrong with that picture:
MIB is apart of the SNMP standard. Again: It is not a protocol.
And mentioning IPv4 and IPv6 on Layer 2 when they stretch over layers 2 and 3.

Just Google for "Simplified OSI Model" to find plenty of good information.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not protocol, it is markup language for design web pages ad show in browser. And above picture is misguiding you . Refer this site for tcp/ip 
[https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-network-tcp-ip-model](https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-network-tcp-ip-model.)

Hope you are now clear with it.